# Creating a Time window in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

How to create a time window in solidity .. so that you will allow a function call for example with in 2 hours .. I know timers do not exist in solidity so how do I only allow a function to be called within a certain period of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **two** methods: Either you estimate the the block number of the beginning and end of your period, and do

```
require (block.number < ##yourStartBlock## && blocknumber < ##yourEndBlock##)
```

or you use block.timestamp, where an integer represents the [unix time stamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) of the block. This is only as precise as the miner wants it to be, meaning block.timestamp can turn out to be anything between the block.timestamp of the last and the next block.

```
require (block.timestamp < 1521379216 && block.timestamp < 1521343200)
```

where `1521379216 == 03/18/2018 @ 1:20pm (UTC)`
and

```
1521343200 == 03/18/2018 @ 3:20am (UTC)
```

Comment: how can I say the current block.timestamp + 2 hours? .. to make it generalized

Comment: just like that: uint endTime = block.timestamp + 2 hours;
then use it like require(block.timestamp < endTime); 
See 
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html